# Excel 2010 Insert new row and copy original row if two conditions met

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet full of customer details where the customer may have had one or two products. Product1 is indicated in column U, Product2 in column V.

If the customer has purchased both products I need to duplicate the row then leave the Product1 code as is and set Product2 to NO in the first row, and in the second row set Product1 to NO and leave the Product2 code as is.

The spreadsheet can have 100's of rows - can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A question like this is probably more appropriate for https://superuser.com/

But I will show you one of the many ways you could do this:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]
[image: image5]

Of course you could write a macro to do this, you could use functions to do this - this is a simple task and has many different solutions.

But this method is an example of very basic excel usage and only requires a knowledge of sort and autofill and copy/paste. Good Luck.